# Excel Formula to sum value if date falls in particular month

Tags: excel, date, sum

I am trying to make a table in excel which calculate sum of some values if a date falls in a particular month.

[image: Image to my spreadsheet]

On the column A are dates, on column B some values, on column E are only listed numbers from 1 to 12 and in column F there are cells with `=SUM(IF(MONTH($A$1:$A$10)=E11; $B$1:$B$10; 0))` formula.

I dont really know why on `F9` the value is 0 even if checked with the debuger (F9 key) and saw that the result of the foruma is 22, which is the expected value. Also, I dont know why on `F11` and `F12` I receive an error: `A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type`

What can I do to solve this problems? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem. I surounded the foruma with curly brackets ( `{ }` ) and now works

Comment: It's possible to use `SUMPRODUCT`, then formula doesn't need "array entry", e.g. this formula in F1 copied down `=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$1:$A$10)=E1)+0;$B$1:$B$10)`

Answer (score 0):

For versatility and perhaps speed in a large spreadsheet I think you might consider a PivotTable. So label your two columns (say `Date` and `Value`), insert a PT with `Date` for ROWS and Sum of Value for VALUES, then Group...,  Years (avoids summation of the same month but different year) and Months.